# printing with java in linux

Tags: java

Does anyone know any good tutorial or howto how to print with java application in linux? In search but i can not find any good tutorial.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the printer is attached and working for your Linux box, a Java application will be able to print too. However, there are few cases, sometimes, when you don't get desired results. For that you must refer to [the official guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jps/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried / seen http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

Delegate the actual printing to `lp`, just as every other solution does.

Comment: You need to generate the actual bytes too.  The print framework helps with that.